# Is there a list with all the available options for --resource= in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a cluster role in kubernetes, is there a way to see all the available options for `--resource=`  ?

Because the manual only show me this:
`--resource=[]: Resource that the rule applies to`

Comment: The [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/) reference lists all of the objects and all of their fields.  I'd highly recommend checking YAML files into source control and `kubectl apply`ing them rather than trying to create objects imperatively using `kubectl` with command-line options.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 kubectl api-resources --verbs=list -o name
```

This list all the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it,
We can see the resources by running:

```
kubectl api-resources
```